# How can we get the approximate values $a,b,c$?

Tags: relations

How can we get the approximate values $a,b,c$?

The condition and relation are the followings :

1. $0 < a,b,c < 1$
2. $a + b + c = 1$
3. $(1-a)^2 + b^2 + c^2 =1 $

Comment: It seems that are infinitely many solutions. This can be osberved by substituting 2. in 3. which leads to $b^2+bc+c^2=1$ and the positive solutions of this equation lies on a kind of ellipse centered in the origin. Do you want them all or just one?

Comment: The complete conditions are equivalent to $b^2+bc+c^2=0.5$ with $0<b,c<1$.

Comment: @user31415 yes thanks was a typo.

Comment: @user31415 I think they can be reduced further to $b^2+bc+c^2=1/2$ with $0<b,c$.

Comment: @user31415 The points on the ellipse already satisfy the inequality $<1$. The ellipse condition makes that inequality superfluous.

Comment: That's true - b and c will both be < $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to approximate.  You can simplify 2 and 3 together to give

$b^2 + bc + c^2 = \frac{1}{2}$

Combine that with 1 and you get an infinite set of solutions, one that has a completely defined relation between $b$ and $c$, with actually tighter limits on $b$ and $c$.  $a$ is always just $1 - (b+c)$.